# How can I get the view from an activity?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I know that this works on an onClick event handler:

```
public void NextPage(View view)
{
    View parentView = (View) view.getParent();
    parentView.setBackground(images[imageNumber]);
}
```

This works great.  I am able to grab the parent view of the imagebutton that was clicked.  The background of my current activity view is set to the Drawable images array.

I am, however, trying to get this same view elsewhere using:

```
View parentView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
parentview.setBackground(images[imageNumber]);
```

This doesn't work.  I believe that the view being returned is not the correct view.  I may be getting the view of my main activity.

EDIT:

So I have 2 activities.  My MainActivity and my SecondActivity.  After a button click in the MainActivity I start my second activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);         
startActivity(intent);
```

In my SecondActivity my background has the potential to change.  1 way to change it is to click 1 one 2 buttons. That is done by the NextPage code above and it works perfectly so long as I have access to the correct view.

There are other times I want to change the background, however, I don't seem to have access to the correct view.  I'm not sure how to find the same view as the click event NextPage is able to find.

Comment: are you getting a crash or it just does not do anything?

Comment: **"...trying to get this same view elsewhere..."** - Where is "elsewhere"?

Comment: Did you tried just getWindow().getDecorView() ? Also usualy you can set an id for the view that you are setting as a content view on the activity, this way you can get it in onCreate() after you add the view as the contentView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a button on this same page so I just grabbed that button and got its parent view:

```
myButton.parentView();
```

Probably not the best solution, however, it works!